# Macbook 13" retina trackpad stuck

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, display

My trackpad is stuck in the downer position, it doesn't "click up" again. I can still use my trackpad for tapping and it functions just like before but I cant click it so it goes down, it is stuck down there. Did anyone else have this problem, if so how did you fix it?

(To be clear, this is not the common software issue, this is pure hardware. The trackpad is stuck).

Comment: How do you know it is not the software ?

Comment: Did you spill liquid on it, is there a dirt stuck there, in any case give it a good clean (with computer off)

Comment: What year is the retina... if it's 2012 you can open up the laptop and see the underneath of the trackpad. Not exactly easy but no exactly hard either. Go to ifixit.com

Comment: Bring it to a Genius Bar.

Comment: its the first 13" retina. I havn't spilled anything on it. Guess i will have to bring it to an apple store...

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is having the same problem out there, this may not be the best solution but it worked for me. 
My trackpad had been clicking just fine anywhere on it. Suddenly it would only press down in the left bottom corner.
I simply, closed the laptop,  flipped it over and slapped it hard in corresponding area where the trackpad is. I also lightly tapped it on all sides on a soft surface (my couch). Sure enough that did it. Been fine since for over a year now.
I guess something must have been stuck underneath it.

Comment: I'll second Flower's answer (since I'm not allowed to comment). Turned over my mid-2012 15" Retina Pro and slapped it a few times, all better. Thanks, Flower!

Comment: This technique worked for my 2015" Retina Macbook Pro which had the same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My first macbook, the normal unibody had this problem too, I fixed it by putting a folded post-it between the battery and the underside of the trackpad.
As unmircea says, this is harder to do on a retina but still possible.
If you are still under warranty I wouldn't risk it though.

Comment: If the person still has warranty, bringing it to a Genius Bar would help out, or call Apple (or get to a premium reseller if a genius bar is too far away)

Answer (score 0):

early 2013 macbook pro 15"retina display. Trackpad stopped clicking. High volume compressed air around edges while holding down pad worked after 3 tries. Whew, saved me expense and trip to Apple store.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the year of your laptop, there is actually a screw that dictates the clicking of the trackpad. It's possible the screw has become lose, however, it's an odd shaped screw, and it might be best to take it in to a repair center. It is also possible that your battery has expanded, as the battery sits directly below the trackpad, and it is not allowing your trackpad to click correctly. In either scenario, I would suggest taking it to a repair center/ Apple Store.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution. I have the late 2013 macbook pro with retina display. My trackpad click is erratic. I could get it click if I pressed on the trackpad thinking that my battery was expanded and inhibiting the trackpad. But this solution was fleeting and not consistent.
I tried to slip a thin paper in the seam and work it around the trackpad. Some areas are blocked by the device but you can get around the perimeter, even the corners, with a piece of paper. At the office, I found the back sheet on a stack of post-its worked the best.
I did not recall spilling anything on the trackpad but I did see the paper bring up some dirt. I suspect this is the detritus from everyday use.
After the wipe (and some judicious compressed canned air) the pad is much more responsive. I expect that unless I pull the bottom off and the battery, that gunk is going to hand out there. This may become a regular maintenance routine.
I just tested it again after typing this message -- and it is still working!
I tried the tapping and slapping and it only worked sporadically. I didn't want to risk hitting this thing too much. Also, the edges seem to accumulate the debris which gets removed by the paper.
The space is very narrow. On my machine it is wider on the left than the right. You can't see the gap on the right but the paper will slide in there. Even around the corners.
I have gotten into the habit of leaving the air can on my desk to keep all the donut crumbs at bay!